# Haven't handled the FileNotFoundException file in Java program?

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors, java-io, filenotfoundexception

I have some trouble finding the file in a java program in mac system.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class Data{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        File file = new File("/Users/project/test.txt");
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

In the same directory, when I typed this command Javac Data.java, it would give this error

I have read multiple similar posts on StackOverflow, but unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution.

```
Data.java:9: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
                         ^
1 error
```

I have tried setting the file path like:

```
    "./test.txt"
    "test.txt"
    "/text.txt"
```

But still, the same error would occur.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I can only run the java command in the terminal in the ~ directory, and all the above java files are in the ~ directory too.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This is not 'trouble finding a file'. This is a compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not throwing an exception. Your error message does not mean that the `FileNotFoundException` is thrown.

You have a compile time error.

Whenever you open a file, it must be like this:

```
try {
    File file = new File("/Users/tianrongzhen/project/test.txt");
} catch (Exception e) { 
    // handle exception here
}
```

Or like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("/Users/tianrongzhen/project/test.txt");
    // rest of your code
}
```

There are 2 kinds of exceptions: Checked and Unchecked.

A Checked exception can be considered one that is found by the compiler, and the compiler knows that it has a chance to occur, so you need to catch or throw it.

For example, opening a file. It has a chance to fail, and the compiler knows this, so you're forced to catch or throw the possible `IOException` or `FileNotFoundException`.

There is a huge difference between the two ways to handle exceptions above.

First one catches and handles `Exception` internally, so the caller doesn't have to do any exception handling.

Second one throws `Exception`, so the caller needs to handle the `Exception`.

Based on the question you have asked here, I would recommend you to read up on the basics on exception handling. [Here](https://stackify.com/specify-handle-exceptions-java/) is one resource, but feel free to explore.